# Шейдер не получает тень

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

На данный момент я пишу простенький шейдер для травы в Unity и у меня возникли проблемы: шейдер не принимает тень. ShadeSH9 всегда возвращает одно и то же значение. Другие объекты в сцене тень отбрасывают и принимают.

Код шейдера: https://pastebin.com/2PAM5YLu

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

**EDIT**:

Код Subsurf.cginc: https://pastebin.com/seW913Yi

Comment: Простенький? Что он делает?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, траву...

Comment: Исчерпывающе, а как?

Comment: Берёт поверхность, подразделяет её с помощью hull/domain шейдеров, геометрический шейдер превращает каждую точку поверхности в травинку (части травинки создаются в несколько циклов). Затем для каждого треугольника расчитывается diffuse и к rgb каналам добавляется ambient, рассчитываемые из изначальной точки.

Comment: #include "Subsurf.cginc" бы еще

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, туда я поместил HULL и DOMAIN шейдеры. Могу скинуть, но не вижу особого смысла.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, добавил ссылку на Subsurf в вопрос. На всякий случай.

Comment: Спасибо, просто если ничего не запустить то и взглянуть на на что

Comment: Насколько мне удалось понять из гугла ShadeSH9 в юнити получает запеченые тени.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, у меня в сцене двигается только игрок. Все остальные объекты статичны, но тени всё равно нет. Я думаю, что стоит попробовать написать на форум самого Unity. Попробую.

Comment: Тени запекать надо вручную, там в lighting есть кнопка bake

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, задам глупый вопрос: где "lighting"?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GlobalIllumination.html

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ничего не изменилось. У меня, кстати, стояла галочка "auto generate", так что вряд ли проблема в этом.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да, проблема где-то в настройках. Я скопировал код примера из Манула, но он не сработал.